# How to get process name based on port number

Tags: c#, sharppcap

How can I get all the processes name (applications) based on the IP address and/or port? I am using C# and I'm getting all the TCP/UDP connections using sharppcap library and I want to know which applications uses those connections.

Thank you!

Comment: You could get output of `netstat` command, which will give list of process IDs along with port numbers, then you can get the process name using System.Diagnostics.Process class.

Comment: Refer this API doc , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid